# Database Error on Update

Tags: database-error

I am trying to update EE v2.4 to v2.10.1 and got a database error.

Error Number: 1060

Duplicate column name 'can_search'

ALTER TABLE exp_member_groups ADD COLUMN can_search char(1) NOT NULL default 'n'

Filename: updates/ud_0_00_09.php

Line Number: 112

Not sure what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Something funky is going on with how your current install is reporting its version... that's the script to update your EE version up to EE0-0.9. That script shouldn't even be running... what is set in your config file for the `app_version` config key?

Comment: $config['app_version'] = '240';

Comment: Add the period and try again, `2.4.0`

Answer (score 0):

Refresh the browser to continue the upgrade. If that doesn't help contact EllisLab support.